# EvtQuery error ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER Windows 2008 works on windows 2008 r2

Tags: windows, api, events, logging

I am using the new windows event api (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), to query some events from a remote system.

I have created a 32 bit application using runs on Windows 2008 R2 (64 bit), in 32 bit mode.
But when I run this application on windows 2008 32 bit (sp2), I am getting error on the call of EvtQuery.
The last error code reported by this is 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER).

I am wondering what could be wrong when I am running Windows 2008.

Any pointers.

thanks
Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN says that if you provide structured xml in query which has path value, the Path parameter is ignored, in following function call.

EvtQuery(
  *In*  EVT_HANDLE Session,
  *In*  LPCWSTR Path,
  *In*  LPCWSTR Query,
  *In*  DWORD Flags
);

But that worked for windows 2008 r2 and was not working on windows 2008. When I added Path value instead of NULL it worked on Windows 2008 as well.

Thanks,
Nikhil